# Change background color of contained link when table row is hovered over

Tags: css

I've been using the following jquery code to style table rows.

```
$('tr').hover(function() {  
    $('tr td').css('color', '#ffffff'); 
    $('tr td a').css('background', '#0080ff');  
});

$('tr').mouseleave(function() { 
    $('tr td').css('color', '#222222'); 
    $('tr td a').css('background', '#ffffff');
});
```

This works just fine but I'm wondering there's a CSS alternative. It would seem like a much more efficient approach than what I have right now but I really don't know a whole lot about CSS.

The problem with using the following CSS

```
tr:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
}
```

is that the anchor tags still remain the same color when the table row is hovered on. Are there any ways via CSS that hovering on a table row could trigger the anchor tags nested inside of the given table row to change colors?

Comment: tr:hover a { close question }

Comment: `tr:hover a { /* ? */ }` - I don't use CSS though, and I think `:hover` support has historically been sketchy.

Comment: I find it interesting that your JavaScript is very similar to the CSS equivalent. I suggest you reading up on the CSS syntax more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sort of depends on your other CSS selectors, but this will probably work:

```
tr:hover td {
    color: white;
}


tr:hover td a {
    background: #0080ff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. This works perfectly. I had a feeling that it was something simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
td:hover a {
    your link style on row hover
}
```